# why success function is not working in spring mvc

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

on clicking submit button in jquery,the below ajax call is made, but its success function is not working..

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "hai.htm",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "application/json",
                    data:{
                        name:name,
                        pass:pass,
                       },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                     var obj = JSON.parse(data);  
                      alert(obj[0].name);
            }   
             error: function (error) {
                alert('error; ' + eval(error));
                console.log(error);
            }             
                })
```

the controller class image is shown here

my controller class is

```
package com.safecare.spring;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "hai")
    public @ResponseBody Map hai(@RequestParam(value = "name",required = false) String name,@RequestParam(value = "pass",required = false) String pass) {
        Map ma=new HashMap();
       ma.put("name", name);
       ma.put("pass", pass);
        System.out.println(name);

        return ma;

    }
}
```

the error message is as follows:
" The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."

Comment: are you sure the call is success?

Comment: yes iam.but why ?

Comment: Try adding 'error' function too. It seems your call ended up with an error. Are you sure about the url given?

Comment: Instead of calling the controller you are calling an htm file. change the url by the url to your controller.

Comment: no.its not correct..

Comment: when i add error function it return json object by error..

Comment: @shihabve: Always try not to post image but text when pasting code samples.

Comment: @SabirKhan:ok i will do...

Comment: put a debugger in controller and first make sure that controller is getting called & response returned. That will rule out incorrect url doubt. Secondly , put error method in script too.

Comment: @SabirKhan:added error function now data is returned with an alert as{error; [object,object]}

Comment: @shihabve ajax is expecting a json value but you are returning map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem has solved.
use GSON  in controller class.

```
@Controller
public class controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "hai")
    public @ResponseBody String hai(@RequestParam(value = "name",required = false) String name,@RequestParam(value = "pass",required = false) String pass) {
        Map ma=new HashMap();
       ma.put("name", name);
       ma.put("pass", pass);
        System.out.println(name);
        Gson ob=new Gson();
        ob.toJson(ma);

        return ob.toJson(ma);

    }
```

thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerName")
public class Controller{
    @RequestMapping(value="/hai", ... )
    public @ResponseBody String hai( ... ) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name", name);
        obj.put("pass", pass);
        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

Then update your ajax as,

```
               $.ajax({
                    url: "/ContextPath/controllerName/hai",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:{
                        name:name,
                        pass:pass,
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                        alert(data.name);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
```

In the url replace '/ContextPath' with your Context Path.